# Using dedicated Graphics with Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: graphics, windows-phone-7.1

I have 2 cards on my laptop: Intel HD 4000 and GeForce 630. I would like to set that Windows Phone Emulator will use only the GeForce not Intel. The manager has blocked preferences(see screen)

http://postimage.org/image/l1l3qpz31/

Using Intel graphics generates errors in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, so here's what I did:

1. Found a "Windows Phone Emulator" shortcut in the start menu.
2. Right-clicked on it and selected "Run with graphics processor" -> "High-performance NVIDIA...".
3. After emulator with an image loaded up, I went to VS and selected to run my application on the emulator.